# Any/ None/ All of + Proper noun

Tags: proper-nouns

> 1. I don't know **any of** Noah, Oliver, and Sophia.
> 2. I know **none of** Noah, Oliver, and Sophia.
> 3. I know **all of** Noah, Oliver, and Sophia.

I would like to know whether the sentences above I created are correct.

I think it may be more natural to rewrite the first and second sentences as follows:

> I don't know Noah, Oliver, or Sophia.

I think it may be more natural to rewrite the third sentence as follows:

> I know Noah, Oliver, and Sophia.

Comment: All three sentences are incorrect, because you list the names. If you replaced the names with a phrase like 'the Smith children' or 'your three friends', the sentences would be correct.

Comment: I already know the usage you mentioned.  I would like to know whether "Any/ None/ All of A, B, C, ..." are correct.  You say they are incorrect.  If so, I want to know how to express the meaning of "All" or "None" in this case.

Comment: "I don't know [either] Noah, Oliver or Sophia." "I know Noah, Oliver and Sophia."